# Laravel Routes using Middleware with an OR in list of Middleware or other method

Tags: php, laravel, permissions

I am using the Spatie permission and roles package for Laravel.  I wanted to try and check the permission and roles in my web routes.php file in Route Groups, but that doesn't seem to work because the Auth::user() does't have the Spatie functions attached in the routes.  That must happen somewhere else.  I say that because I get a call to member function on NULL.

What I am currently doing is something like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum', 'verified']], function () {

        Route::post('/Reports/getallhl7_reports', [ReportsController::class, 'getallhl7_reports'])->name('getallhl7_reports');
        Route::post('emailReport', [UtilitiesController::class, 'emailReport'])->name('emailReport');
});
```

and then in the Controllers checking the permissions and roles like:

```
protected function getallhl7_reports(Request $request) {

    if (Auth::user()->can('provider_data') || Auth::user()->can('staff_data')) {
        return Reports::getallhl7_reports($request->input('StudyInstanceUID'));
    }
}
```

What I might want to do is to check the permissions in the routes or routes groups instead of in the Controller, but like I said the Spatie functions are not available in the Route Groups (After the Group, but before the Route) for some reason, and using an OR in the Middleware seems to be problematic.  You can check for permissions in the Group, but I think that is an AND and not an OR, like:

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum','verified', 'permission:provider_data', 'permission:staff_data']], function () {
```

It isn't clear to me how I could check permissions using this format:

```
Route::post('emailReport', [UtilitiesController::class, 'emailReport'])->name('emailReport');
```

by modifying it with something to verify some set of permissions before invoking the Controller.

Comment: if you are adding 2 middleware then they are ANDs but the permission middleware can accept multiple permissions which would be an OR

Comment: Ahh !  The Spatie permissions can be multiple:  'permission:provider_data', 'permission:staff_data' vs. ??.  I guess I could look it up also.